# ATM (Automated Teller Machine) Terminal Application

Tags: java

I consider myself a beginner in Java. Therefore I want to improve and learn about Java(8) and OOP as much as I can. Feedback about:

- performance
- clearn code

is very much appreciated.

If you could review with regard to these questions, then I'd be very grateful:

- Is having multiple returns in the function `pinIsValidFor` a bad pattern? How would you write it differently?
- Are the classes too long (they nearly got 300 lines of code)? What would be a good size for a Java-class

This is "*Automated Teller Machine Terminal Application*" in Java:

You can do typical transaction like deposit, withdraw, and show balance. It persistently saves your transactions in an external file so you can see your changes after restarting the application.

It also (tries to) handle all exception cases.

[GitHub](https://github.com/thadeuszlay/18_bankAccount)

Main file (not much in here)

```
import controller.Atm;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Atm.start();
    }
}
```

In the model folder I got my AccountCard file:

```
package model;

import model.exceptions.DepositNegativeBankTransfer;
import model.exceptions.ExceedLimitTransfer;
import model.exceptions.OverdrawBankTransfer;
import model.exceptions.ZeroBankTransfer;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

public class AccountCard {
    private String pin = null;
    private int amount = 0;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH");

    private Map<String, Integer> transferHistory = new DefaultLinkedHashMap<>(0);

    public AccountCard(String pin, int amount, String withdrawDate, int timesWithDraw) {
        this.pin = pin;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.transferHistory.put(withdrawDate, timesWithDraw);
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public String getPin() {return this.pin;}

    public boolean isPinCorrect(String pinInputByUser) {
        return this.pin.equals(pinInputByUser);
    }
    public int getBalance() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void withdrawAmount(int withdrawAmount) throws OverdrawBankTransfer, ZeroBankTransfer, ExceedLimitTransfer {
        if (withdrawAmount > this.amount) throw new OverdrawBankTransfer("Withdrawal exceed balance.");
        if (withdrawAmount == 0) throw new ZeroBankTransfer("Withdrawing of zero amount is forbidden.");
        Date now = new Date();
        if (isTransferExceedLimit(now)) throw new ExceedLimitTransfer("Limit of numbers of withdrawals exceeded");
        this.amount -= withdrawAmount;
        logBankTransfer();
    }

    private boolean isTransferExceedLimit(Date date) {
        String now = dateFormat.format(date);
        return transferHistory.get(now) > 3;
    }

    private void logBankTransfer() {
        Date date = new Date();
        String now = dateFormat.format(date);
        int timesWithDrawCurrent = transferHistory.get(now);
        transferHistory.put(now, ++timesWithDrawCurrent);
    }

    public void depositAmount(int depositAmount) throws DepositNegativeBankTransfer, ZeroBankTransfer {
        if (depositAmount < 0) throw new DepositNegativeBankTransfer("Invalid operation. Deposit amount is negative");
        if (depositAmount == 0) throw new ZeroBankTransfer("Depositing of zero amount is forbidden.");
        this.amount += depositAmount;
    }

    public String getWithdrawDate() {
        String withdrawDate = "";
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : transferHistory.entrySet()) {
            withdrawDate = entry.getKey();
        }
        return withdrawDate;
    }

    public int getTimesWithDraw() {
        int timesWithDraw = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : transferHistory.entrySet()) {
            timesWithDraw = entry.getValue();
        }
        return timesWithDraw;
    }
}
```

In my controller folder I got my Atm-file:

```
package controller;

import controller.helper.Helper;
import model.AccountCard;
import model.exceptions.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class Atm {

    final static String ACCOUNT_PATH = "files/account.txt";
    final static String PIN = "PIN";
    final static String AMOUNT = "amount";
    final static String LASTWITHDRAW = "lastWithdraw";
    final static String TIMESWITHDRAW = "timesWithDraw";
    final static int MAX_PIN_INPUT_COUNT = 3;
    final static String IRRECOGNIZABLE_PIN = "XXX";

    static boolean atmIsActivated;
    static boolean cardIsInserted;
    public static void start() {
        atmIsActivated = true;
        while(atmIsActivated) {
            redrawConsole();
            System.out.println("Press ENTER to insert card");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            cardIsInserted = (scanner.nextLine() != null);
            if (cardIsInserted) {
                AccountCard account = loadCardInformation();
                transactionalManipulationOf(account);
            }
        }
    }

    private static AccountCard loadCardInformation() {
        String pin = null;
        int amount = 0;
        String withdrawDate = null;
        int timesWithDraw = 0;
        try (
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader(ACCOUNT_PATH);
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fReader);
        ){
            while(true) {
                String line = bReader.readLine();
                if (line == null) break;
                if (line.equals(PIN)) {
                    pin = bReader.readLine();
                } else if (line.equals(AMOUNT)) {
                    amount = Integer.parseInt(bReader.readLine());
                } else if (line.equals(LASTWITHDRAW)) {
                    withdrawDate = bReader.readLine();
                } else if (line.equals(TIMESWITHDRAW)) {
                    timesWithDraw = Integer.parseInt(bReader.readLine());
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            try {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't find card");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                Helper.printErrorMessage(e1);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                throw new CardReadFail("Can't read card information");
            } catch (CardReadFail cardReadFail) {
                Helper.printErrorMessage(cardReadFail);
            }
        }
        return new AccountCard(pin, amount, withdrawDate, timesWithDraw);
    }

    private static void redrawConsole() {
        final String ANSI_CLS = "\u001b[2J";
        final String ANSI_HOME = "\u001b[H";
        System.out.print(ANSI_CLS + ANSI_HOME);
        System.out.flush();
        System.out.println("********* ATM *********");
    }

    private static void transactionalManipulationOf(AccountCard account) {
        redrawConsole();
        while(cardIsInserted) {
            showMainMenu();
            processUserSelection(account);
        }
    }

    private static void processUserSelection(AccountCard account) {
        String userInput = Helper.getUserInput();
        switch (userInput.toLowerCase()) {
            case "w":
                withdrawFrom(account);
                break;
            case "d":
                depositTo(account);
                break;
            case "s":
                showBalanceOf(account);
                break;
            case "e":
                returnCardOf(account);
                break;
            default:
                printUnknownOperation();
        }
    }


    private static void showMainMenu() {
        System.out.println("=======Main-Menu=======");
        System.out.println("What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("Withdrawal \t\t(w)");
        System.out.println("Deposit \t\t(d)");
        System.out.println("Show Account \t(s)");
        System.out.println("Exit \t\t\t(e)");
        System.out.println("________________________");
    }

    private static void printUnknownOperation() {
        System.out.println("Unknown operation please try again");
    }

    private static void returnCardOf(AccountCard account) {
        redrawConsole();
        saveCardFor(account);
        System.out.println("Card returned. Thanks for using our ATM. Have a nice day. :)");
        cardIsInserted = false;
    }

    private static void saveCardFor(AccountCard account, String pin) {
        try (
            FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(ACCOUNT_PATH);
        ){
            fWriter.write(PIN + "\n");
            fWriter.write(pin + "\n");
            fWriter.write(AMOUNT + "\n");
            fWriter.write(account.getBalance() + "\n");
            fWriter.write(LASTWITHDRAW + "\n");
            fWriter.write(account.getWithdrawDate() + "\n");
            fWriter.write(TIMESWITHDRAW + "\n");
            fWriter.write(account.getTimesWithDraw() + "\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                throw new CardSaveFail("Save card failed. Transaction made in this session were not saved!");
            } catch (CardSaveFail cardSaveFail) {
                Helper.printErrorMessage(cardSaveFail);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void saveCardFor(AccountCard account) {
        saveCardFor(account, account.getPin());
    }

    private static void showBalanceOf(AccountCard account) {
        redrawConsole();
        Locale currentLocale = Locale.US;
        int amount = account.getBalance();
        NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);

        System.out.println("Your current balance is now " + currencyFormatter.format(amount));
    }

    private static void depositTo(AccountCard account) {
        redrawConsole();
        System.out.println("How much do you want to deposit?");

        int depositAmount = Helper.getIntegerUserInput(Helper.getUserInput());

        if(pinIsValidFor(account)) {
            try {
                account.depositAmount(depositAmount);
                showBalanceOf(account);
            } catch (DepositNegativeBankTransfer depositNegativeBankTransfer) {
                Helper.printErrorMessage(depositNegativeBankTransfer);
            } catch (ZeroBankTransfer zeroBankTransfer) {
                Helper.printErrorMessage(zeroBankTransfer);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Transaction canceled");
        }
    }

    private static boolean pinIsValidFor(AccountCard account) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your PIN to execute transaction");
        int trials = 0;
        while (trials < MAX_PIN_INPUT_COUNT) {
            String userInput = Helper.getUserInput();
            if (account.isPinCorrect(userInput)) return true;
            if (userInput.equals("c")) return false;
            printWarningMessage(++trials);
        }
        if (trials >= MAX_PIN_INPUT_COUNT) killCardFor(account);
        return false;
    }

    private static void printWarningMessage(int trials) {
        System.out.print("Incorrect PIN. ");
        Map<Integer, String> warningMessage = new HashMap<Integer, String>(){
            {
                put(1, "Please try again");
                put(2, "You typed in your pin wrong twice already. This is your last try");
                put(MAX_PIN_INPUT_COUNT, "You typed in the pin wrong trice. Transaction aborted. \n Your card is now invalid.");
            }
        };
        System.out.println(warningMessage.get(trials));
    }

    private static void killCardFor(AccountCard account) {
        saveCardFor(account, IRRECOGNIZABLE_PIN);
        cardIsInserted = false;
        System.out.println("Card killed");
    }

    private static void withdrawFrom(AccountCard account) {
        redrawConsole();
        System.out.println("How much do you want to withdraw?");
        int depositAmount = Helper.getIntegerUserInput(Helper.getUserInput());

        if(pinIsValidFor(account)) {
            try {
                account.withdrawAmount(depositAmount);
                showBalanceOf(account);
            } catch (ExceedLimitTransfer exceedLimitTransfer) {
                Helper.printErrorMessage(exceedLimitTransfer);
            } catch (OverdrawBankTransfer overdrawBankTransfer) {
                Helper.printErrorMessage(overdrawBankTransfer);
            } catch (ZeroBankTransfer zeroBankTransfer) {
                Helper.printErrorMessage(zeroBankTransfer);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Transaction canceled");
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to that I created different custom Exception classes to handle exceptions, a custom LinkedHashMap, and a Helper-class for recurring methods. All of them can be inspected here: [GitHub](https://github.com/thadeuszlay/18_bankAccount)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for sharing the code.

Here is what I think about it:

## Naming

Finding good names is the hardest part in programming, so always take your time to think about the names of your identifiers.

On the bright side you follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

But in Java there is an exception for *boolean* variables and methods: they should start with `is` or `has` like instead of `atmIsActivated` it should be `isAtmActivated`.

## Entry class.

In general it is a good thing to have a tiny entry class. We usually use it to switch from *static* context to *object* context.

Your entry class simply delegates to another static method in a different class. Therefore it is almost useless.

## OOP

Doing OOP means that you follow certain principles which are (amongst others):

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")
- favor polymorphism over branching 
  Interfaces, abstract classes, or inheritance support that principles and should be used as needed.

In that sense your code really does implement some of the OO principles.

But your entire program is in *static* context with is bad for a couple of reasons (especially for a "training" program):

- no polymorphism
- no dependency injection
- hard to UnitTest

If you would actually use objects instead of just `static` methods you could make that code simpler and easier to extend.

The typical example is the switch in your method `processUserSelection`:
the OOP approach to this is to define a common interface for the operations.

```
interface AtmOperation {
  void operateOn(AccountCard account);
}
```

The we have a separate class for each operation (mot likely in its own class)

```
class WithdrawOperation implements  AtmOperation {
  @Override
  void operateOn(AccountCard account){
  }
}

class DepositOperation implements  AtmOperation {
  @Override
  void operateOn(AccountCard account){
  }
}

class BalanceOperation implements  AtmOperation {
  @Override
  void operateOn(AccountCard account){
  }
}
```

Some of that operations need resources from the ATM:

```
class BalanceOperation implements  AtmOperation {
  /* pretend we have a class AtmConsole with methods .redraw() and .println() */
  private final AtmConsole console;
  public BalanceOperation( AtmConsole console){
     this.console = console;
  }
  @Override
  void operateOn(AccountCard account){
     console.redraw();
    Locale currentLocale = Locale.US;
    int amount = account.getBalance();
    NumberFormat currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);
    console.println("Your current balance is now " + currencyFormatter.format(amount));
  }
}

class InputErrorOperation  implements  AtmOperation {
  private final AtmConsole console;
  public BalanceOperation( AtmConsole console){
     this.console = console;
  }
  @Override
  void operateOn(AccountCard account){
    console.redraw();
    console.println("Unknown operation please try again");
  }
}
```

There are different ways to access this implementations. The easiest way is to put them in a *Map* when you initialize the ATM:

```
// ...
private final Map<String,AtmOperation> operations = new HashMap<>();
private final AtmConsole console = new AtmConsole();
private final AtmOperation invalidInputOperation = new InvalidInputOperation(console);
public static void start() {
    operations.put("w",new WithdrawOperation(console));
    operations.put("d",new DepositOperation(console));
    operations.put("s",new BalanceOperation(console));
    operations.put("e",new ReturnCardOperation(console));
    atmIsActivated = true;
// ...
```

then your method `processUserSelection`   would change to:

```
private static void processUserSelection(AccountCard account) {
    String userInput = Helper.getUserInput();    
    AtmOperation operation =   operations.getOrDefault(userInput.toLowerCase(),invalidInputOperation);
    operation.operateOn(account);
}
```

benefits are:

- configurations, definition and usage of the operations are clearly separated.
- you can change the operations without changing the place(s) where they are used.
- you can put each operation in its own class file
- you can easily write UnitTests for each operation to verify and document their behavior.

---

> I assume the AtmConsole is the console of the Atm where all the transactional information and main menu is displayed. How would the AtmConsole look like?

Im my world there could be different console types. Therefore I had an AtmConsole interface:

```
interface AtmConsole{
   void redraw();
   void println(String message);
    /* most likely it should also handle the input
       Because it is the User Interface: */ 
   String aqireInput();
}
```

And This would be my implementation:

```
class AtmConsoleCommandLine implements AtmConsole {
  private final Scanner input;
  public AtmConsole(Scanner input){
    this.input = input;
  }
  @Override
  public void redraw() {
    final String ANSI_CLS = "\u001b[2J";
    final String ANSI_HOME = "\u001b[H";
    System.out.print(ANSI_CLS + ANSI_HOME);
    System.out.flush();
    System.out.println("********* ATM *********");
  }
  @Override
  public void println(String message){
     System.out.println(message);
  }
  @Override
  public String aqireInput(){
    return input.nextLine();
  }     
}
```

---

> In the function returnCardOf I set the value of the global variable isCardInserted to false.

As an experiences programmer you should know that global variables usually do more harm than good in any language... ;o)

> How would I do this if the returnCardOf function is in a class of it's own? Would I make the returnCardOf into a reference object and pass it as an argument into returnCardOf?

This is a question of *separating concerns*

Although the state "is a card inserted" seems to belong to the ATM itself, There is another place where it could belong: The `AccountCard` has no meaning outside the ATM (as far as your program is concerned) Therefore it could also hold the information of being rejected. So you could move the global variable to this class and add the methods `isInserted()` and `release()`.

On the other hand:

Although there is a pattern not to use *Exception* for flow control: I think that releasing the Card from the ATM is an "unhappy" event ultimately finishing the program.

So IMHO having the release object throwing an exception that is cough in the loop is a valid option.

Comment: Thanks for your review. Great stuff! But one question: I assume the `AtmConsole` is the console of the Atm where all the transactional information and main menu is displayed. How would the AtmConsole look like?

Comment: In the function `returnCardOf` I set the value of the global variable `isCardInserted` to `false`. How would I do this if the `returnCardOf` function is in a class of it's own? Would I make the `returnCardOf` into a reference object and pass it as an argument into `returnCardOf`?

Comment: Thanks again. Can you also explain to me how I can implement the function `killCardFor`? As you can see the method `killCardFor` uses inside the method `saveCardFor`.  How would you implement it in OO approach? Would you pass an instance of the class `saveCardFor` into the function ``killCardFor`?

Comment: @thadeuszlay Yes. *persistence handling* is a responsibility of its own and should therefore live in its own class where you could pass an instance of into the class doing  `killCardFor`.

Comment: Is it really necessary to pass in the  `console` (of type `AtmConsole`) into the operations? Can't I just instantiate a new console instance within the operation? Wouldn't that work as well?

Comment: @thadeuszlay *"Can't I just instantiate a new console instance within the operation? Wouldn't that work as well?"* Yes, that would work as well. *But* it makes your code inflexible. Imagine that you want to change the console from a command line to a GUI. With your approach you have to change each and every implementation of `AtmOperation`. With the *dependency inversion*-approach you can simply pass in that other implementation of `AtmConsole` to the unchanged operation instances.

Comment: @thadeuszlay In addition: I personally think that a class should not be responsible for the instantiation of its dependencies and therefore I consider it a violation of the SRP.

Comment: I hope I correctly understood your suggestion. Please have another look at the updated code here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162772/atm-automated-teller-machine-terminal-application-followup

Answer (score 1):

As you specifically asked about the multiple returns in `pinIsValidFor`, I will focus on that question.

First of I have to agree with Timothy that you should really create instances of objects instead of having everything `static`.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with having multiple returns. Some programmers prefer to not have it, but I disagree with that. Personally I prefer to *return early*. That is, handle some edge cases as soon as possible and return the appropriate value from there. **IF** you would *not* use multiple returns, the code would be a lot harder to follow.